# How to pass join query in laravel to view route

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I have this route passing Notification model:

```
Route::view('masaya', 'pages.notifications-table', [
    'data' => App\Notification::all()
]);
```

How do i pass this query to instead of the model:

```
$inspect = DB::table('notifications')
    ->leftJoin('franchises', 'franchises.id', '=', 'notifications.franchise_id')
    ->leftJoin('units', 'units.id', '=', 'notifications.unit_id')
    ->select('franchises.id as fid', 'franchises.case_number', 'franchises.authorize_units', 'franchises.deno', 'franchises.route_name', 'franchises.expiry_date', 'franchises.date_granted', 'units.id as uid', 'units.plate_number', 'units.motor_number', 'units.chassis_number', 'units.make', 'notifications.id', 'notifications.remarks', 'notifications.created_at', 'notifications.plate_picture')
    ->orderBy('units.updated_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: @Autista_z with all the query?

Comment: 'data' => $inspect = DB::table('notifications') . . . 

this gives mo error sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a result set that you would use often, you could have a static method in your `App\Notification` model such as:

```
public static function withFranchisesAndUnits()
{
    return \DB::table('notifications')
        ->leftJoin('franchises', 'franchises.id', '=', 'notifications.franchise_id')
        ->leftJoin('units', 'units.id', '=', 'notifications.unit_id')
        ->select('franchises.id as fid', 'franchises.case_number', 'franchises.authorize_units', 'franchises.deno', 'franchises.route_name', 'franchises.expiry_date', 'franchises.date_granted', 'units.id as uid', 'units.plate_number', 'units.motor_number', 'units.chassis_number', 'units.make', 'notifications.id', 'notifications.remarks', 'notifications.created_at', 'notifications.plate_picture')
        ->orderBy('units.updated_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20);
}
```

.. and just call it like this:

```
Route::view('masaya', 'pages.notifications-table', [
    'data' => App\Notification::withFranchisesAndUnits()
]);
```